# rmcorr: Pass column name with variable

Tags: r, string, correlation, do.call

I am trying to use [rmcorr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmcorr/rmcorr.pdf) R package for data analysis of repeated samples.

I want to make it go through all pairs of columns and estimate their correlation. The problem is `rmcorr` accepts only unquoted column names as arguments:

`>> rmcorr(Subject, PacO2, pH, bland1995)`

So, an expression like `rmcorr(colnames(bland1995)[1], colnames(bland1995)[2], colnames(bland1995)[3], bland1995)` throws an error:

```
Error in rmcorr(colnames(bland1995)[1], colnames(bland1995)[2], colnames(bland1995)[3],  : 
  'Measure 1' and 'Measure 2' must be numeric
```

So I hoped `do.call` would help me. Haha, fat cha

```
>> do.call('rmcorr', args = list(colnames(bland1995)[1], colnames(bland1995)[2], colnames(bland1995)[3], bland1995))
Error in rmcorr("Subject", "pH", "PacO2", list(Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  'Measure 1' and 'Measure 2' must be numeric
In addition: Warning message:
In rmcorr("Subject", "pH", "PacO2", list(Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L,  :
  'Subject' coerced into a factor
```

How do I pass string variables to such a kind of function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `get`:

```
rmcorr(participant = get('Subject'), 
       measure1 = get('PacO2'), 
       measure2 = get('pH'), 
       bland1995)

Repeated measures correlation

r
-0.5067697

degrees of freedom
38

p-value
0.0008471081

95% confidence interval
-0.7112297 -0.223255
```

Comment: Is there a way to enter a variable though? `...get(column_1)...` fails me. Strangely, only when I set a string variable in a function

Comment: What do you mean? If I save `a <- 'Subject'` and use `get(a)` it still works.

Answer (score 2):

The most recent update (0.3.0) of the rmcorr package should allow this now. Column names can still be entered without quotes, but they can now also be entered dynamically with strings. Trying your example after the update:

```
rmcorr(colnames(bland1995)[1], colnames(bland1995)[2], colnames(bland1995)[3], bland1995)

Repeated measures correlation

r
-0.5067697

degrees of freedom
38

p-value
0.0008471081

95% confidence interval
-0.7112297 -0.223255
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I've come up only with this ugly duckling:

```
combs = combn(c(2:(ncol(bland1995))), 2)
for (i in c(1:ncol(combs))){
  j = combs[1,i]
  k = combs[2,i]
  temp = bland1995[,c(colnames(bland1995)[j], colnames(bland1995)[k], 'Subject')]
  colnames(temp) = c('tax1','tax2','Subject')
  s = rmcorr(Subject, tax1, tax2, temp)
  print(x)
}
```

I wish there was a more concise way